# how to stretch a navigation so it takes over the whole div

Tags: html, css

I have a nav div with following properties:

```
#nav {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

but when I put in a navigation bar in it ..it is not stretching for the whole width of `960px`

link: [here](http://cloudninetech.com/newsite/site/homepage.html)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what it is you want, are you wanting the lis in your menu to automatically change in size to distribute to the width of the ul?

Comment: yes, I am trying to make the li's in the ul spread evenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to your stylesheet:

```
.sf-menu { width: 100%; }
```

That will make your `ul` tag take the full width of your `#nav` div. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, or if you want each `li` to take the full width.

If you want each `li` element to be evenly stretched across the full width, in your case with 4 elements you can simply set the width of them to 25%. For variable amount of `li` tags, I'd have to think about it some more...

```
.sf-menu li { width: 25%; }
```

Comment: I tested this code before my answer and saw that it causes some problems in the 2nd level of navigation. It needs to be .sf-menu > li to work as you hope.

Comment: Rather than using the child selector (not supported by IE6), I would suggest using:
.sf-menu li li { width: inherit; }

Answer (score 1):

Add these rules to your stylesheet:

```
#nav > ul {width: 100%;}
#nav > ul > li {width: 25%;}
```